Relationship between PGFs and Moments?
I am trying to understand the relationship between Moments and Probability Generator Functions (PGF).
As I understand, the PGF $ G_X(s)$ of a discrete random variable $ X$ that takes non-negative integer values is defined as:
$$ G_X(s) = \mathbb{E}[s^X] = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P(X = k) s^k $$
I read this relationship between the kth Moment and PGFs:
$$G_X(s) = \mathbb{E}[s^X] = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P(X = k) s^k $$

For k = 1: $ E[X] = G_X'(1) $
For k = 2: $ E[X^2] = G_X''(1) + G_X'(1) $
For k = 3: $ E[X^3] = G_X'''(1) + 3G_X''(1) + G_X'(1) $
etc.

I am trying to understand why this above relationship is true.
I tried to verify this relationship for the first and second moments:
1) First Moment (Mean)
Differentiate the PGF:
$$ G_X'(s) = \frac{d}{ds} G_X(s) = \frac{d}{ds} \left( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P(X = k) s^k \right) $$
Apply the derivative inside the summation:
$$ G_X'(s) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P(X = k) \frac{d}{ds} (s^k) $$
Compute the derivative:
$$ \frac{d}{ds} (s^k) = k s^{k-1} $$
Substitute back into the summation:
$$ G_X'(s) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P(X = k) k s^{k-1} $$
Evaluate at $ s = 1$:
$$ G_X'(1) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P(X = k) k \cdot 1^{k-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k P(X = k) $$
This sum is the definition of the expected value $ \mathbb{E}[X]$:
$$ G_X'(1) = \mathbb{E}[X] $$
2) Second Moment
Differentiate the PGF a second time
$$ G_X''(s) = \frac{d}{ds} G_X'(s) = \frac{d}{ds} \left( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P(X = k) k s^{k-1} \right) $$
Apply the derivative inside the summation:
$$ G_X''(s) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P(X = k) k \frac{d}{ds} (s^{k-1}) $$
Compute the derivative:
$$ \frac{d}{ds} (s^{k-1}) = (k-1) s^{k-2} $$
Substitute back into the summation:
$$ G_X''(s) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P(X = k) k (k-1) s^{k-2} $$
Evaluate at $ s = 1$:
$$ G_X''(1) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P(X = k) k (k-1) \cdot 1^{k-2} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k (k-1) P(X = k) $$
Doing some algebra, we can see that:
$$ \mathbb{E}[X^2] = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k^2 P(X = k) $$
$$ k^2 = k(k-1) + k $$
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k^2 P(X = k) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left[ k(k-1) + k \right] P(X = k) $$
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k^2 P(X = k) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k (k-1) P(X = k) + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k P(X = k) $$
The first term, $ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k (k-1) P(X = k) $, is exactly $ G_X''(1) $.
The second term, $ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k P(X = k) $, is the mean $ \mathbb{E}[X] $, which we have from the first derivative evaluated at $ s = 1 $:
Thus in total, we can see that this is related to the first and second derivatives of the PGF:
$$ \mathbb{E}[X^2] = G_X''(1) + G_X'(1) $$

Proof for the $K^{th}$ moment . I am not sure how to do this - I got stuck here is my attempt:

$$ G_X(s) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P(X = n) s^n $$
$$ G_X'(s) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P(X = n) n s^{n-1} $$
$$ G_X''(s) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P(X = n) n(n-1) s^{n-2} $$
We can see a pattern. Take the kth derivative:
$$ G_X^{(k)}(s) = \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} P(X = n) n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-k+1) s^{n-k} $$
Evaluate this at s = 1:
$$ G_X^{(k)}(1) = \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} P(X = n) n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-k+1) $$
Look at the kth moment of X:
$$ E[X^k] = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^k P(X = n) $$
I tried to expand $n^k$ using the falling factorial notation:
$$ n^k = n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-k+1) + \text{lower order terms} $$
Substituting this into the expression for $E[X^k]$:
$$ E[X^k] = \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-k+1) P(X = n) + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\text{lower order terms}) P(X = n) $$
The first term in this sum is exactly $G_X^{(k)}(1)$. The second term involves lower order derivatives of G_X evaluated at 1. So we can write:
$$ E[X^k] = G_X^{(k)}(1) + \text{combination of lower order derivatives} $$
I am not sure if this proves the general relationship between the kth moment and the kth derivative of the PGF evaluated at $s = 1$.
Can someone please help me correct my proof?

As you've seen, taking the derivatives of the PGF gives you what are called the factorial moments
$$\mathbb{E}((X)_k) = G^{(k)}(1).$$
To get the moments from here requires expressing the polynomial $x^n$ in terms of the falling factorials $(x)_n$. This expansion has coefficients given by the Stirling numbers of the second kind
$$x^n = \sum_{k=0}^n S(n, k) (x)_k$$
which gives
$$\mathbb{E}(X^n) = \sum_{k=0}^n S(n, k) \mathbb{E}((X)_k) = \sum_{k=0}^n S(n, k) G^{(k)}(1).$$
An alternative way to prove this is to show that
$$\mathbb{E}(X^n) = \left( \left( s \frac{d}{ds} \right)^n G(s) \right) \bigg\vert_{s=1}$$
and figure out how to expand $\left( s \frac{d}{ds} \right)^n$ in terms of $s^k \frac{d^k}{ds^k}$. There's a combinatorial argument that gives the same answer as above, or one can write down a recursion.

@ Qiaochu Yuan : Do you think what i have done this is correct?

This is my other question on proving properties of PGFs: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4953130/connection-between-taylor-series-and-probabilities

@wulasa: what you've done is correct so far but it's incomplete. You haven't said what the lower order terms are (and it's not so obvious; the Stirling numbers are not as famous as the binomial coefficients, eg).

thank you ... can you please expand it if you have time? I am going to work on it as well...

What does the notation $\left( s \frac{d}{ds} \right)^n $ mean, please?

@Ryan: it means to apply the differential operator $s \frac{d}{ds}$ $n$ times. This operator has the property that $\left( s \frac{d}{ds} \right)^n s^m = m^n s^m$ so it is exactly the thing needed to get the moments.
