Connection between Taylor Series and Probabilities
I am trying to understand why the coefficients in a PGF represent the probability of $X=k$. This is something I always accepted as true without ever actually understanding why it is true.
I start from the basic definition of a PGF:
$$ G_X(s) = \mathbb{E}[s^X] = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} p_k s^k $$
Where:

$X$ is a discrete random variable
$p_k = P(X = k)$ is the probability that $X$ takes the value $k$ (i.e. $p_k$ are the coefficients)

I first tried to expand the expectation:
$$ \mathbb{E}[s^X] = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} s^k P(X = k) $$
I used the notation $P(X = k) = p_k$, so we can write:
$$ \mathbb{E}[s^X] = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} p_k s^k $$
Taking the the nth derivative of $G_X(s)$ and evaluate it at $s = 0$:
$$ \frac{d^n}{ds^n} G_X(s) = \frac{d^n}{ds^n} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} p_k s^k $$
Using the power rule of differentiation:
$$ \frac{d^n}{ds^n} G_X(s) = \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} p_k \cdot k(k-1)(k-2)...(k-n+1) s^{k-n} $$
And finally evaluating at $s = 0$:
$$ \left.\frac{d^n}{ds^n} G_X(s)\right|_{s=0} = n! \cdot p_n $$
Rearranging:
$$ p_n = \frac{1}{n!} \left.\frac{d^n}{ds^n} G_X(s)\right|_{s=0} $$
This last equation shows that we can recover the probability $p_n$ by taking the nth derivative of the PGF, evaluating it at $s = 0$, and dividing by $n!$. My interpertation is that the coefficient $p_k$ in the PGF expansion directly represents the probability $P(X = k)$, which is the probability of the event happening at that point $k$.
Is this the correct reason as to why the coefficients in a PGF represent the probability of $X=k$ ?

PS : Taylor Series Connection:

While we are on the topic, I also wanted to solidify my understanding as to how PGF's relate to Taylor series expansion.
In general, a Taylor Series expansion of a function f(x) around a point a is given by:
$$ f(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + \frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2 + \frac{f'''(a)}{3!}(x-a)^3 + ... $$
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n $$
Keeping this in mind, let's consider the PGF expanded around $s = 0$ via Taylor Series:
$$ G_X(s) = G_X(0) + G_X'(0)s + \frac{G_X''(0)}{2!}s^2 + \frac{G_X'''(0)}{3!}s^3 + ... $$
$$ G_X(s) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{G_X^{(k)}(0)}{k!}s^k $$
Connecting PGF and Probabilities together, we see:
$$ p_n = \frac{1}{n!} \left.\frac{d^n}{ds^n} G_X(s)\right|_{s=0} = \frac{G_X^{(n)}(0)}{n!} $$
This means that the coefficient of $s^k$ in the Taylor series expansion of $G_X(s)$ around $s = 0$ is exactly $p_k$, the probability that $X = k$. It appears that the PGF is essentially a Taylor series expansion around $s = 0$, where the coefficients are the probabilities $p_k$.

Bravo! It says we can recover the coef's of a converging power series with non-negative coef's.

@ Ryan Shen: Can you please take a look at this question ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4957479/number-of-coin-flips-before-a-certain-condition-is-reached
